# Как декодировать URL сайта?

Tags: url, веб-программирование, javascript

Дело в том, что я люблю парсить сайты на Javascript. Всем известно, что кирилические УРЛ при копировании со строки браузера встают в коды %АА и другие. Их можно вернуть в человеческий вид с помощью decodeURI. Но вот мой робот в процессе работы наткнулся на невероятно ужасный сайт, который, видимо, сам кодирует URL. Вот этот код выдает ошибку:

```
decodeURI("http://www.forum.nedug.ru/showthread.php?11499-%EA%E0%EB-%F7%E5%F0%ED%EE%E3%EE-%F6%E2%E5%F2%E0");
```

> `malformed URI sequence`

Как мне обойти такие ужасные сайты? Как знать, какой на самом деле у них УРЛ (битый или норм)?

Comment: Так как правильного ответа не последовало, я решил сам решить проблему. Решение вылилось у фунцкию.

function decodeURISafe(uri)
{
 var res;
 try
 {
  res = decodeURI(uri)
 }
 catch(e)
 {
  res = uri;
 }
 return res;
}

Заменил ВСЕ функции decodeURI на decodeURISafe. Уже проверил, работает чётко. Ну а против уродливых сайтов я ничего не могу сделать, придется смотреть на их ужасные УРЛ :(

Answer (score 3):

Меньше криков, больше разума)

Все не так плохо и тем более ошибка (невнимательность) здесь ваша. А все потому, что страница, на которой вы это парсите - в UTF8 (2bytes/char), а `forum.nedug.ru` в CP1251 (1byte/char). Разбирайте заголовки META, смотрите кодировку в них (**charset=windows-1251** например) и приводите все к utf-8.

А вообще неблагодарное это дело - парсить сайты на JS, и ваш вопрос - одна из причин.

Comment: Абсолютно с вами не согласен, насчет того что на JS парсить сайты - неблагодарное дело и вот почему - браузер приводит любые страницы к валидному виду (учитывая частую криворукость вебмастеров, а также их не желание соответствовать стандартам и лишний раз заглянуть на htmlbook.ru) это решает много проблем, а добавьте сюда что-нибудь по типу jQuery с ее селекторами (и прочими вкусностями) и работа с DOM деревом облегчается в разы. К тому же jquery позволит весьма элегантно  отправить распарсенные данные на сервер аяксом.

Comment: Ага, только библиотеки для парсинга в php есть и они работают, а библиотеки для перекодировки (1252-юникод например) под js я, конечно, встречал, но с каким-нибудь нетбуком это муки адские. Хотя, возможно, кому-то это нравится, не спорю.

Да и дело даже не в этом. Это утилита "для себя", не больше, потому что такую штуку еще и кроссбраузерной делать - да я лучше руками данные вытаскивать буду) Имеется в виду не вытаскивание тайтлов, а что-то посерьезнее да с обработкой.

Comment: PHP не заточен для работы со сгенерированным контентом, в отличии от JS. Хм, да проблемы с кодировкой могут возникнуть, но стоит указать у стрички с js парсером туже кодировку что и у контента, который предстоит парсить, и проблема исчезает :). Я бы даже сказал, что это дело привычки - наверно, по началу будет тяжело, но как только выработается общий алгоритм, набьется глаз и рука парсеры на js станут обыденностью :)

Comment: Вообще-то сайт выкачивается на РНР через CURL, потом обрабатывается на PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, и все это возвращается в JavaScript для дальнейшей обработки. Проблема кодировки уже давно решена, любой сайт автоматически кодируется в UTF-8 посредством iconv. Кривой сайт, это точно! Зайдите через новейшую Firefox или Opera!

Comment: Ммм понимаете в чем дело) **`%E5`** в юникоде не изменится. Поэтому надо сначала декодировать с `rawurldecode`(получите ссылку в win-1251), а потом уже конвертировать в юникод.

Comment: Вообще-то причем УРЛ до этих кодировок? УРЛ я вообще-то вставляю(CTRL+C, CTRL+V) со строки Фаерфокса в поле input. В этом поле стоит .bind() который через полсекунды пытается превратить %E5 в нормальную кирилицу. Но он выдает "malformed URI sequence", потому что сайт выдает неправильный УРЛ.

Comment: Блин, вы если занялись таким извратом - пишите/ищите аналог **rawurldecode** для JS или отправляйте аяксом этот URI на сервер и там декодируйте.  *Malformed URI* выдается в том числе из-за разницы в кодировках. **%EA** - код буквы "к", **верный** код в кодировке windows-1251, а в юникоде неверный. Так яснее?

decodeURI(-Component) != rawurldecode.

Answer (score 1):

С форумом там всё в порядке. У меня, например, ссылки видны нормально

**http://www.forum.nedug.ru/forumdisplay.php?76-Лечение-за-рубежом**

Это говорит о том что они ничего сами принудительно не кодируют.

Ищете аналог php функции rawurldecode(); для JavaScript :-)

Comment: или    urldecode();

Comment: Я вставил вашу ссылку в 4 браузера. Firefox и Opera "вернули" УРЛ до безобразного вида "...%CB%E5%F7%E5...", Хром и эксплорер оставили кирилические. Все браузеры самые новые. Это они полюбому что-то кодируют!

Comment: Следуя вашей логике можно подумать что в Хроме и Эксполере есть механизм который декодирует то что какбэ "закодировали" на форуме, тут семи пядей во лбу не надо чтобы понять что это бред. Ответом выше Sh4dow уже на всё ответил.

Comment: Кстати, если вставить http://www.forum.nedug.ru/showthread.php?11499-%EA%E0%EB-%F7%E5%F0%ED%EE%E3%EE-%F6%E2%E5%F2%E0 вот это в таком виде в Хром и Эксплорер, то оно таким и остается.